# How to handle API rate limits with a Context Manager?

Tags: python, contextmanager

I'm trying to write a context manager to handle a `GitHub` rate limit exception.  Essentially, I want it to listen for the error, and when it occurs, dynamically pull the reset time (all done through the `GitHub` API), and wait for that amount of time.  At which point I'd like it to resume the program, and do this as many times as necessary to complete the job.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def api_rate_manager(api_obj: g3.GitHub):
    # Check for the API ratelimit being exhausted.  Limited to 5k
    # requests per hour.
    try:
        yield
    except GitHubError as e:
        if 'rate limit exceeded' in e.msg.lower():
            info = g3.rate_limit()['resources']['core']
            reset = mu.convert_unix_timestamp(info.get('reset'))
            delta = reset - datetime.now()
            sleep(
                delta.seconds + 1)  # Add a second to account for milliseconds
```

Currently, it will correctly catch the error and wait, but then it just exits the program (which makes sense) instead of circling back around to continue.  I know that I could put a check in the code to see what the remaining limit was, and wait if it reached 0, but I wanted to practice context managers.

It would be used in the following way:

```
        with api_rate_manager(gh):
            for commit_iter in commit_iters:
                handler: gu.EtagHandler = commit_iter.etag_handler
                for commit in commit_iter:
                    if not commit:
                        continue

                    commit.refresh()
                    author_data: dict = commit.commit.author
                    data = {
                        'sha': commit.sha,
                        'author': author_data.get('name'),
                        'author_email': author_data.get('email'),
                        'create_date': author_data.get('date'),
                        'additions': commit.additions,
                        'deletions': commit.deletions,
                        'total': commit.total
                    }
                    mu.add_etl_fields(data)
                    writer.writerow(data)
                    has_data = True
                etag: str = commit_iter.get_etag()
                if etag:
                    logger.info(f'Etag for {commit_iter.name}: {etag}')
                    handler.store_in_db(etag=etag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the context manager uses `yield` (like in a generator), it generates only once. [See contextlib's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html).

As a result, in case the exception is caught in your context manager, the execution resumes after `yield` and exits.
You may want to invert the order of the context manager and of your main iteration. See my example below.

Context manager:

```
import contextlib
from time import sleep

@contextlib.contextmanager
def api_rate_manager():
    try:
        yield
    except KeyError as e:
        print('sleeping')
        sleep(3)
```

Test case 1:

```
a = {0:0,1:2,2:4,3:6,5:10}

with api_rate_manager():
    for i in range(8):
        print(a[i])
```

Outputs:

```
0
2
4
6
sleeping
```

Test case 2:

```
for i in range(8):
    with api_rate_manager():
        print(a[i])
```

Outputs:

```
0
2
4
6
sleeping
10
sleeping
sleeping
```